# python function Namerror: name 'dictionary' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, if-statement

I would like to load a file and convert it to a dictionary. then, would like to use the loaded file to display the data. user input for choice is between 1 and 2, in order to decide which function to run.
The catch is if I press 2 before 1 then it will display the message "dictionary is empty". Again, when I load the file and try to run display data, it is showing "Nameerror: name 'dictionary' is not defined"
The code is as below: (Thanks in advance)

```
def load_data():
  import csv
  open_data = open('file.csv', 'r')
  datasets = csv.reader(open_data)
  mydict = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in datasets}
  return mydict

def display_data(my_dict):
  ds = my_dict
  if ds == {}:
    print("dictionary is empty")
  else:
    for key, value in ds.items():
      print(key)
      print(value)
       
def main():
    while True:
    choice = int(input("select 1 or 2"))    
    if choice == 1:
      my_dict = load_data()
      print(my_dict)    
    elif choice == 2:
      display_data(my_dict)
main()
```

Comment: with choice 2 you don't have any dictionary to display, Should it have done `my_dict = load_data()` also? In that case, the load could be before the if since its used in both cases.

Comment: @tdelaney I have fixed it, it will be display_data(my_dict)

Comment: That's close, but `my_dict` hasn't been assigned in the `else`. You'll need to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all.The code you provided has many faults.
The key point is you should use a variable **my_dict** to store the dict you load or display the empty dict if type 2 before 1.

Try the code list below:

```
import csv


def load_data():
    open_data = open('file.csv', 'r')
    datasets = csv.reader(open_data)
    mydict = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in datasets}
    return mydict


def display_data(my_dict):
    ds = my_dict
    if ds == {}:
        print("dictionary is empty")
    else:
        for key, value in ds.items():
            print(key)
            print(value)

    
def main():
    my_dict = {}
    while True:
        choice = int(input("select 1 or 2"))    
        if choice == 1:
            my_dict = load_data()
            print(my_dict)    
        elif choice == 2:
            display_data(my_dict)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined any `my_dict` in `line 24`, that is why it is giving a `name error`.
You shall add the line :

```
my_dict = {}
```

If you want your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

In choice 2 you have no data or haven't assigned any value to my_dict before calling `display_data` you should load those data in my_dict and pass it to the function
Here is the code

```
def load_data():
  import csv
  open_data = open('file.csv', 'r')
  datasets = csv.reader(open_data)
  mydict = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in datasets}
  return mydict

def display_data(my_dict):
  ds = my_dict
  if ds == {}:
    print("dictionary is empty")
  else:
    for key, value in ds.items():
      print(key)
      print(value)
       
def main():
    while True:
        choice = int(input("select 1 or 2"))    
        if choice == 1:
          my_dict = load_data()
          print(my_dict)    
        elif choice == 2:
          my_dict = load_data()
          display_data(my_dict)
main()
```